# Is there a way to loop inside Where clause?

Tags: c#, linq

There are two lists `"ObjlistA"` and `"ObjlistB".`

```
var newList = from someObg i ObglistB
       where [condition = true if some property of any element in the list ObjlistAA equals  someObg's some property]
       select someObg
```

Is there a way to loop inside the where clause, so that the obj's property can be compared with each and every element's property in the list?
Can anyone help me out the "Where" part?

Comment: Do you want the query like which we have in SQL, i.e. where testCol IN ('A', 'B', 'C')..?? Is it kind of this..??

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var newList = ObjlistB.Where(someObj => ObjlistA.Any(a => a.SomeProperty == someObj.SomeProperty))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
where ObjlistA.Any(x => x.Property == someObj.Property)
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean this?

```
    var newList = from someObg in ObjlistB
                  where ObjlistA.Any(a => a.ID == someObg.ID)
                  select someObg;
```